# Make the network profile editable on the main Stack Exchange page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stackexchange.com, network-profile

Currently, the Stack Exchange Network Profile links to all the network accounts and acts as a centralized profile page. Seeing that the ability to edit the profile is available from the profile pages of all *.SE sites, I think the ability to edit profiles should be available on that Network Profile page as well.

It will be consistent with the nature of the centralized profile page and will better the user experience.

EDIT: As the current Network profile, is actually the oldest profile on the Network, providing an edit option on the Network profile which links to the oldest profile edit page, would be one way to implement this.

Comment: You wouldn't be editing a network profile (no such thing exists), you'd be editing the profile *of your oldest user on the network*, so presenting it as a network-wide edit would be a very disingenuous representation of what's happening.  Linking you to the oldest profile to edit...that I could definitely see happening.

Comment: @NickCraver If I understand this correctly, all profiles across the network get synced with the main/oldest profile once in 24 hours. Is that correct? In which case, the oldest profile, serves as the network profile. Then, yes, clicking edit on the network profile page should/could take you to the oldest profile for editing. Or you could actually make the network profile work like a network profile and reverse sync it. All profiles get synced with whats on the Network page.

Comment: No such sync happens, no...you press a button if you want them syced on the edit page.  We allow you to have every profile be different, sycning is entirely optional and not automated at all.

Comment: @NickCraver Is there any FAQ that explains/documents the profile behavior? It appears that I am a little out of depth here.

Comment: @Nick aren't there plans for such network wide profile though? I'm almost sure that I saw someone say something on this a while ago.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've never heard of such a discussion internally...would be news to me.  Asheesh - I'm sure there is on meta, but I'd post a question here asking for it to be added to the new help center and see what people think - that was my delay on answering that comment :)

Comment: @Nick hmm... OK guess you know better than me, lol! :)

Answer (score -1):

There is now a way to update your network profile, albeit a little indirectly as shown in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/363954) by Adam Lear.

1. First, visit [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).
2. You'll then need to click on the tiny "Update profile info" in your network profile.

> [image]

3. You can then select which site to import data from.

It is good to note that this is a one time operation and can be repeated each time you want your profile to be updated via another one.

Comment: This isn't really editing, you don't change any existing details. You just choose which site to "feature" on the network profile. Also, note that against common sense, when you do edit the details on the site you chose, this is **not reflected** in the network profile and you have to re-synch it with that site for the changes to appear.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I mentioned all of that in my answer. And it is still much better than nothing and accomplishes what was wanted.