# Don't force sync with my oldest account on my network profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, network-profile, profile-sync

I tend to put information on my profiles that's relevant for that particular site.

For example, my profile on Stack Overflow says what languages and technologies I'm familiar with and currently working in, my profiles on ELU and ELL say that I'm a native speaker of English and what dialects, my profile on Pets says what pets I keep and have kept in the past, etc. On sites where there's nothing specific relevant, I leave it blank.

My network profile syncs with my oldest site, which is Stack Overflow. But it just doesn't make any sense for me to have information about programming-specific stuff on the network profile.

It's already been asked [whether there is a way to edit that profile independently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231419/how-can-i-edit-my-network-profile-independently), but since there has been no answer in nearly a year, I assume it's not possible. (Further, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230025/251229) to another question says that there is no way to leave the global one blank.)

So I'm requesting it.

Ways it could be done (in descending order of helpfulness):

- Allow network profile to be edited independently (already requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132239/more-control-on-profiles-network-wide))
- Allow users to change which site gets synced from
- Allow users to delete their "about me" on the network profile

The first would be best, but it's already been suggested and not much done about it. The others would at least allow slightly more control.

[This request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137933/allow-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-accounts-to-exclude-selected?rq=1) is also related, but it's talking about manual sync, not automatic sync.

Comment: Second option "Allow users to change which site gets synced from" seems helpful to [me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260934/260388)

Answer (score 27):

Starting today, you can choose which profile to sync to stackexchange.com:

1. Click the "update link":

   > [image]
2. Pick a site:

   > [image]
3. ???
4. Profit.

Note that this is a *one time* copy, not an ongoing sync. If you want to update your profile on stackexchange.com after making changes on your Q&A site of choice, you'll need to repeat this process.

Let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: @Sally Automatic sync is gone entirely, except for users who don't have a user profile on stackexchange.com itself. (FWIW, it was never automatic so much as triggered when someone visited the profile.) If there's a big demand for it, we can revisit this implementation.

Comment: :O!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working correctly. I synced my profile to my MSE one and it's reset to my SO one (my oldest) twice now.

Comment: Bug reported - [When creating a new account, my SE network profile is reset to the text entered for the new account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277870/my-se-profile-keeps-resetting-to-my-stack-overflow-profile-despite-me-selecting)