# Network profile about me parent account setting

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, profile-sync

I think *about me* on the network profile synchronises with the oldest account of the user (for example: for me, it is [Ask Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask_Ubuntu)).

But I want that it would be synchronised with another account (say [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)). So, I've the suggestion that on the network profile there should be provided setting for synchronisation with the account that the user would like to set.

In other words, currently it is only synchronisable with the oldest account profile -about me. But what about a feature like a drop-down menu to select an account from which this will be synchronised?

Note: I am not talking about auto-filing of about me when joining a new community/site. I am talking about providing a (site/account) selection setting for about me on the (global) network profile. (*Something like we set the parent user for the chat profile!*)