# Changing Profile Picture Doesn't Work

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I want to change my profile picture. I did all the necessary steps and it changed my profile picture- however, when I reload the page the new profile picture goes back to my old profile picture.

I also tried this with an identicon. Same thing happens.

Ultimately, I can't change it.

Is there a time limit for how often I can change it? I last changed it in December from what I recall.

If not, is this a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though it says "change picture":

> [image]

The change is not immediate, i.e. after changing the picture it's still not in effect anywhere else.

To make it count and actually change your profile, you must click one of the blue "Save" buttons in the bottom of the edit screen, same way you have to do for any other profile field you want to change:

> [image]

The left button will save the new picture only for the site you edit your profile in, and the right button will save it, along with all other profile fields, to all the SE sites you have account in.

Comment: I just ran into this and also think it's poor design. At the very least, the page should make it clear that simply "change picture" isn't enough.

Comment: Indeed, a "changes will be lost" if you close the tab or change page without saving would be nice.

Comment: I hit the "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" but is still not changed in stackexchange.com profile page...

I found out that to chakge in the "stackexchange.com " you need an extra click:

Comment: @gabrielem true, it used to auto synchronize and it was changed [four years ago due to a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254566/dont-force-sync-with-my-oldest-account-on-my-network-profile/275694#275694).

Answer (score 1):

I hit the "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" but is still not changed in stackexchange.com profile page...

I found out that to change in the "" you need an extra click:

Clicking on the little text "Update profile info" and then copy it from one of the community, this only after clicking the "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" button ;)

[image]