# Preview profile info change in Network Account

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, network-profile

We can now [choose which profile to synch (copy, actually, but doesn't really matter) with our network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/152859), which is cool.

However, clicking the "Copy" is final and instant, the change is made right away, and sometimes we don't really remember what information we have on which site.

Can we please have a "Preview" button as well, that will show how the profile is going to look like?

> [image]