# Created a new user at Stack Exchange, but did not get the right username

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, display-names

I just created a new user at the Stack Exchange main site and made a screen name I wanted. But I ended up getting the generic name user527663 and I find no way to change that. https://stackexchange.com/users/8199669

I searched the board and there should apparently be a "Edit Profile & Settings" section. But there is none for me.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to [a recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/152859), stackexchange.com information (display name, avatar, About Me, etc.) no longer synchronize automatically; you must manually update it from one of your sites.

To do that, visit [your own network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), and you'll see "Update profile info" button:

> [image]

Click it, choose the site you want info from, and click "Copy":

> [image]

It is worth to mention, that I have started a feature request asking to fix this behaviour: *[Auto synchronize network profile information in case user never updated it manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277932/auto-synchronize-network-profile-information-in-case-user-never-updated-it-manua)*

Comment: Thanks that worked. I actually tried that with Meta and it did not update. But when I did it with Ask Ubuntu, it worked. That might be a bug or maybe something else went wrong.

Comment: Probably caching, here on MSE your account is very fresh and probably didn't have chance to update in the global cache. Glad you were able to change the name!

Answer (score -2):

Try the URL https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/8199669. The display name can be edited.

Comment: No they can't be edited directly on stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok. meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Won't affect stackexchange.com display name.