# How do I edit my network profile?

Tags: feature-request, support, network-profile

Previously, I remember there was a button to edit your profile and propagate it to all the sites. Now, you edit a site profile and then can go to network profile and import your edit.

Now, there are 100 sites, and aliens have very poor memory to remember which one is the sites was used as latest copy for the network profile. At the same time, I see no way to copy the network profile into a local site profile (to be able to edit it and copy to global profile, achieving the "edit network profile" demand). I would like to have one global profile edited separately and additional per-site profile at every site. What is the recommended procedure to edit your network profile at the moment?

---

From comments, I have got to know that there is no separation between sites and "copy from" is misleading in the Network profile because `Save Profile` button saves your profile globally, at every site. So, once you edit your profile and press it, it makes no sense which profile you copy your Network profile from. It however remains a question how to open your Network profile for editing, once the site/global profile has diverged from the Network profile copy.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. There was a new minor change that allowed you to use whatever site's *about me* you like as your network *about me*. There's also the option to edit one of your profiles and "save changes to all Stack Exchange communities".

Comment: @DEAD The old-good save to all? I do not see that option. I see only Save and Cancel. There is no "save to all SE communities". Probably this option is invisible for aliens.

Comment: Read the little little text below "Save Profile". It says that the default action is saving changes to all SE communities, and if you want only the specific site's *about me* to change, you should click something else.

Comment: @DEAD Ok, it saved the profile to all the sites. It makes me to wonder what it the purpose the have a network profile separately in this case. If Save is global then it makes your save the network profile. Anyway, how do you edit the Network profile, which does not match any site profile?

Comment: Well, network profile is just something to be there. I can bet that not many people see it compared to site profiles, but it's a good way to organize things. Imagine if it wouldn't be there. We'd have a feature request for it on meta.SE.

Comment: @DEAD I do not see how two copies of the same thing and confusion that you can copy the network profile from any site whereas it turns out that all the copies are identical, is "a good way to organize anything". Anyway, I would like to know how to open the network profile for editing.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Longer answer posted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't edit [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) directly, and never could. All the details (which are Display Name, Country, Age, Website link, About Me, and Avatar) are imported from an existing site account.

The import used to be done automatically with the oldest profile, without the need to click anything and without the ability to choose where to import it from, until a [feature request asking to change this behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254566/dont-force-sync-with-my-oldest-account-on-my-network-profile) has been [completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/152859) back in February 2016.

So when one want to change their network profile, they need only to pick the proper site and import it from there. I do agree that when you have different details on each site, and 100+ of these, it's a headache finding the one you want, but it's a really extreme edge case.

Comment: Possibly relevant to mention, that this is not updated after copy. E.g. I changed my name on SO and selected to apply this change to all platforms on the network which was done successfully. The network profile kept showing a *long* outdated name, even though all profiles were updated to a different one. Only after applying copy from SO once again the network profile was updated as well.

Comment: @Koenigsberg I do mention it: "So when one want to change their network profile, they need only to pick the proper site and import it from there".

Comment: I know. But it may not be clear, that even when you imported once and updated the one you imported, this update does not transfer to the network profile, *i.e.* the order is important. Since I ran into this issue myself after reading your response, I added this information for other readers who may experience the same thing.