# I mistyped my username

Tags: support, display-names

I would like my main Stack Exchange name to be "kserwick" not "kserwicl".  (I found I could change it for the meta.)

Can I do this myself or must I ask a moderator like this?

Comment: By any chance I don't see any difference between the name you want and the original name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I edit my network profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283623/how-do-i-edit-my-network-profile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that the [main profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) doesn't update when you "save to all sites" in the Profile Editor of another site.

> [image: Unwanted profile name]

In addition to saving the change to at least one site you need to [go to the main profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) and **copy** another site's profile to it, using the "Update profile info" link, and the resulting selector pop-up:

> [image: Update profile info link]

After clicking that link and choosing which site to copy from simply click on the [Copy] button to complete the operation:

> [image: Site Chooser and Copy button]

Comment: Alright, so it's correct in meta, go to stack exchange, profile button, update profile info, copy from meta, copy.  It doesn't change kserwicl which is the only data I have.  Maybe that's the only thing this operation doesn't change. ? Don't really know.  Thanks to everyone who's contributed to this very small unsolved problem!    I can live with this, but I'd still like to solve it.

Comment: @kserwick, I've updated the answer but [it appears from your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369366/i-mistyped-my-username#comment1232429_369368) that you followed the instructions correctly - and that your name on your main profile has not updated. --- You may wish to try again. After waiting 24 hours, if it still doesn't update and the duplicate listed in the blue banner is of no assistance, you can simply reopen your Support Request or preferably edit it to mention that you followed the advice offered and the problem persists. --- Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob.  It wasn't working last night.  Then after many hours passed I opened an account with another site, and an update from it got the result.  Peace.

Comment: @kserwick We are glad to be of assistance. I also see that your main profile has updated, now.