# How to change my profile picture on my network profile?

Tags: support, network-profile, profile-picture

I've tried changing my profile picture according to [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar) , and it worked fine for all sites. However, on my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/14300013/graywolf), I still see picture from my associated Google account. How do I change this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a profile there, it automatically syncs to your oldest profile on its own schedule irrespective of clicking on the button to copy to all sites. I manually triggered the sync for you and it's updated now.

If you ever do create a profile on stackexchange.com, you'll have to [copy it over manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254566/dont-force-sync-with-my-oldest-account-on-my-network-profile).

Comment: It's no longer possible to create profiles on stackexchange.com, as its login page now redirects to MSE's login page, as part of the discontinuation of OpenID.

Comment: @Sonic It still creates the profile once you're back on stackexchange.com, at least for now.